# How to create a datastore for installing a VM

Tags: vmware, esxi, disk-partitioning

I have just installed VMware ESXi 7 as a virtual machine just for learning. I have seen it is feasible to create nested vms using VMware Player Workstation plus Intel chipset: my testing purpose is to create a virtual machine inside a virtualized ESXi server.

Actually I cannot install any vm, probably due to the fact I have not created any datastore yet.

In order to create a datastore I thought to edit the partition of the free space avalaible (for a linux vm 20GB are enough), but when I try to edit partition I get such summary in which I cannot configure anything at all (see pics).

[image]

Have you any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

When you install SO it's not a good practice to add it as a datastore. Please turn off you VM and add another disk to ESXI. After you boot up server again you will be able to create a new datastore.